# Android (Java) - Авторизация

Tags: android, java

Есть приложение и web-сервер. Регистрацию уже реализовал. А вот как сделать авторизацию? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в android можно сделать вход пользователя по логину/паролю? Либо, как можно сделать так, чтобы можно было входить по тем данным, которые есть в устройстве (логин от google play, например)? От куда начать копать?

Answer (score 1):

[AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)
[Authenticating to OAuth2 Services](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/id-auth/authenticate.html) 
или пилить свой кастыль )

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Костыль, вы имеете ввиду, шифровку? А на самом деле, дайте нормальный ответ, тоже интересно. Сама логика. Если пользователь зашёл в аккаунт, то потом ему не надо будет входить. Это уже значит, что пароль надо сохранять.+ шифровать. А как же тогда потом проверять вошёл ли он или нет?