# Авторизация Java Android

Tags: java, android, mysql

Всем добрый день! Только начал изучать Java Android и пытаюсь разобраться как идет взаимодействие с базой данных и авторизацией в приложении.

К примеру на сайтах PHP подключение к базе данных встроенное и все взаимодействие внутри сайта происходит. А переменные которые нужны для авторизации хранятся в сессиях. И все ок.

Но все что я нашел по приложениям это косвенное взаимодействие с базой. Например на сайте делается PHP файл к которому обращается приложение и получает ответ в формате JSON.

1) Вопрос в том: В целом мне нравится такое решение но я не уверен в его правильности.

2) Вопрос: Плюс я не понимаю как сделать авторизацию и закрытый раздел приложения.

3) Вопрос: Я думаю такой метод как я описал не совсем безопасен и есть ли аналог сессии в Java ?

Помогите разобраться. Если есть примеры простые напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Android (Java) - Авторизация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/248138/android-java-%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: Сделайте API, к которому будет обращаться клиент. На стороне сервера генерируйте токен и при каждом запросе проверяйте его.